# Does SQL Server have feature like Oracle's DBMS_DATAPUMP?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We use Oracle's DBMS_DATAPUMP package to export a set of tables to a single file, and then later import the tables back.  Does SQL Server have an equivalent feature?

I looked into BCP, which is a command-line tool that exports and imports but one file per table.  I also found BULK INSERT which imports from a file (but apparently no BULK SELECT which exports).

Comment: You can use import/export or SSIS package to write your own data loading process. What kind of process you do you need? simply loading data? transforming? ...

Comment: We need to save and load data; we don't need transformation.  And it has to be automatic; the user shouldn't have to determine which tables (i.e., which table names) have to be saved and shouldn't have to fire up Management Studio to save and to load.

Comment: I think the best you can do is preparing a SSIS package. you can make a package using Visual Studio or using Import/Export and save it as a package.